# Mark a checkbox as checked in a word (.docx) form

Tags: xml, ms-word, docx, doc

I'm using ruby/nokogiri to parse a word form and fill the fields.
I've already managed to fill the text fields but I'm having difficulties to check a checkbox.
I've looked on the document.xml and didn't notice any different tags when the checkbox is marked or not

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've found the solution
when a checkbox is checked, there is a tag: `<checked />`
and when it isn't checked it is: `<checked val='0' />`

Comment: Thanks. This works! I hope that the team that made this up is mostly preoccupied with designing Microsoft Word internals.

Answer (score 3):

You need your XML to look like:

```
<w:ffData>
  <w:checkBox>
    <w:size w:val="20" />
    <w:checked w:val="true" />
  </w:checkBox>
</w:ffData>
```

Observe that `w:checked` has the parent `w:checkBox`. Documentation on [CheckBox class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/documentformat.openxml.wordprocessing.checkbox.aspx)

**Alternatively** you can set the default state.

Unchecked: `<w:default w:val="0"/>`

Checked: `<w:default w:val="1"/>`

```
 <w:ffData>
   <w:checkBox>
     <w:default w:val="1" />
   </w:checkBox>
 </w:ffData>
```